# istio-ingressgateway always Waiting for Istio Pilot information

Tags: istio, kubeflow, juju

I'm trying to deploy kubeflow on and [OVH managed k8 cluster](https://docs.ovh.com/gb/en/kubernetes/).

After the initial setup of the k8 cluster, I ran the following commands to install kubeflow, as suggested [here](https://charmed-kubeflow.io/docs/install):

```sh
# install
snap install juju --classic

# get cluster name (should be data-workflow)
# check using `cat ~/.kube/config` 
juju add-k8s data-workflow

# create a controller
juju bootstrap data-workflow tp-controller

# add the model
juju add-model kubeflow

# deploy kubeflow
juju deploy cs:kubeflow

# set url in authentication methods
juju config dex-auth public-url=http://foo.k8s.ovh.net
juju config oidc-gatekeeper public-url=http://foo.k8s.ovh.net
```

I see that the `istio-ingress` charm is always waiting- is this normal?  how can i get this to start?

```sh
$ juju status
Model     Controller     Cloud/Region   Version  SLA          Timestamp
kubeflow  tp-controller  data-workflow  2.9.3    unsupported  12:18:03+02:00

App                        Version                    Status   Scale  Charm                 Store       Channel  Rev  OS          Address       Message
... 
istio-ingressgateway                                  waiting      1  istio-ingressgateway  charmstore  stable    20  kubernetes                Waiting for Istio Pilot information
...

Unit                          Workload  Agent  Address    Ports                                   Message
...                             
istio-ingressgateway/0*       waiting   idle                                                      Waiting for Istio Pilot information
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a bug.  Incredibly, it's mentioned in the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M_Ama8ZY8OQ&t=400s) (at 6:40), but not in the [docs](https://charmed-kubeflow.io/docs/install) (on the same page).  It's also not actually written anywhere on the video description.  Wonderful.

You need to open a terminal on the machine with `kubectl` installed, then run:

```sh
kubectl patch role -n kubeflow istio-ingressgateway-operator -p '{"apiVersion":"rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1","kind":"Role","metadata":{"name":"istio-ingressgateway-operator"},"rules":[{"apiGroups":["*"],"resources":["*"],"verbs":["*"]}]}'
```

The `istio-ingressgateway` service will come up a couple of mins later.